# How to initialize instabug for android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile-development, instabug

I have added compile `com.instabug.library:instabugsupport:1+` to dependency in build grade and synced with gradle files, added

```
Instabug.initialize(this, "your_app_token_here");
```

after `setcontentview` in my `MainActivity`.

However `this` is being underlined as an error.
What am I not doing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The `initialize()` method expects an Application object as a first parameter.

You can use `this.getApplication()` instead, if this is your first Activity, or just create a custom Application class and initialize the SDK in its `onCreate()`